# How do I remove slashes from a string within a variable?

Tags: php

The below code outputs product SKUs from my database exactly as they appear.

```
$sku = $product->get_sku();
```

Returns:

```
*BC01-BL/BL*
```

Given this context, how can I ensure that forward slashes are removed from `$sku`? I've tried using `stripslashes()` but this does not work...

Comment: have you tried to search the documentation for "replace" ?`$sku=str_replace("/","",$sku)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you trying to achieve this `*BC01-BLBL*`, then you can use the `str_replace()` function:

```
<?php

$str = '*BC01-BL/BL*';
$str = str_replace("/", "", $str);
echo $str;
//returns *BC01-BLBL*
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks so much @Burhan! I changed the variable to the following:

$sku = str_replace("/", "", $product->get_sku());

Returns: BC01-BLBL

Comment: Hello, Good luck with your project, happy to help